# Apresentar link preview

Tags: php, html, css

Boa noite, como que faço para criar um link preview como o do facebook? eu nao tenho nem ideia de como fazer aquilo. Se alguém puder me dar uma luz pra saber por onde começo, agradeceria muito.

[image: Imagem]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você é como eu e precisa de soluções simples para problemas complexos te aconselho a usar o LinkPreview. É uma REST API que faz uma preview do link *avá*.
https://www.linkpreview.net/

Tudo o que você precisa fazer é enviar uma solicitação para o LinkPreview com o URL para o qual a visualização do link deve ser gerada.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

após gerar sua API só editar o JSON para o estilo desejado.